# Could we change the chat design just a little bit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, design

[image: Prinscreen with some edits]

Everytime I get into chat on Stack Overflow I go into the elements pane and re-adjust the height on the footer. I don't like looking at the bottom of my screen to see if I'm typing properly or even to see larger chunks of text I might copy+paste into there. You could either give it more height, or make it an adjustable height type of solution.

The background I also tweak cause I'd like to keep my eyesight for a while longer and all that white just stings after a while. This could be a profile personalization where someone could choose what color scheme to use throughout Stack Overflow, I know I'd go for dark right away!

These are my suggestions.

**EDIT**

After seeing webarto and cryptic's comments I thought I'd add a little bit of code to make the chat look as I want mine to look like... Of course coloring is personal preference, the real feature of the question was the adjustable input-area, but just add this code to your browser's console and you get an insta-fix^^

```
$("#chat-body").css("background-color", "#969696");
$("a").css("color", "#FFAF73");
$("#input-area").css("height", "200px");
$("#container").css("padding", "10px 20px 100px 20px");
$("#bubble").find("textarea").css({height:"180px", width:"950px"});
```

Now I basically just saved the script for further use and at the same time gave you a way to see it in action live, hope you enjoy^^

Comment: I don't have any issues with the background, but an adjustable footer sounds like an A+ idea.

Comment: Or just not use full screen?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I'm on a 24" screen, it's not about real-estate, it's about not looking at the bottom of the screen in such a tight rectangle. Makes me claustrophobic, hehehe

Comment: I don't think the background color should be changed as it should go with the rest of SO's colors. If you really want to change it, then nothing is stopping you from making a userscript to do so. It's really a style preference opposed to an actual useful feature, we can't go and honor every request for colors, fonts, etc =oP. However, the adjustable footer is something I've wanted for a long time, and would be a good feature.

Comment: I've written 30k messages in that room and haven't seen problems you mention. **Your** problem could be fixed with few lines of Javascript.

Comment: @webarto: First world problems >.<

Comment: The "theme"/color could be added as a feature in the user profile that could affect every StackExchange website, having 2 or 3 variations like: Default, Gray, Invert. However my main issue is with the chat box and if that is set as adjustable it would suit everyone's personal choice. For now I love F12 :p

Comment: I'd also like to have an adjustable footer. That'd also serve as a swell place to stick arbitrary userscript controls.

Comment: @TimPost Going a bit out of the box here, but it could even have a mini version of a testing ground like jsFiddle or eval.in, where we wouldn't need to get out of SO to test snippets. Even several testing grounds for different coding languages in a tabbed format. Or maybe just a list of the most common ones that would open in a new browser tab xD

Comment: @Fernando what I meant was, don't use a full screen browser. Use a windowed browser. Then you won't be looking at the bottom of the _screen_. Which is what you want, no?

Comment: @ColeJohnson lol, you forgot the "<sarcasm>" tag. +1 for making me laugh. Although my personal fix is the "inspect element", F12 ftw :p

Comment: As soon as I posted the edit, it just came to mind... we all code around here, opening some sort of "personal css" on our user profile and let us make our own adjustments would be awesome